# get average of difference of datetime fields in django

Tags: python, django

In a django application, I have a model like following:

```
class Doe(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to find the average difference of end and start values for this model. I'd prefer not to use an extra column or another patchy solution. What is the django-ish way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine [aggregate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate), [F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) and [Avg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#avg):

```
Doe.objects.all().aggregate(average_difference=Avg(F('end') - F('start')))
```

Comment: This returns a float value as the 'average_difference'. (0.025... in my case). What is the meaning of this value in the context of datetime objects?

Comment: It turns out it is the number of days, so in this case it is around 1/40 of a day

Comment: When I tried this, I got: `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.timedelta'`.  Do you happen to know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @ErwinJunge answer, to handle `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number` issue.

Create your own `Avg` class which will work with `timedelta` total seconds value:

```
from datetime import timedelta

class AvgTimeDelta(Avg):

    def convert_value(self, value, expression, connection, context):
        if value is None:
            return value
        if isinstance(value, timedelta):
            value = value.total_seconds()
        return float(value)
```

Then use it in the `aggregate` method:

```
average = Doe.objects.all().aggregate(
    average_difference=AvgTimeDelta(F('end') - F('start'))
)['average_difference']
```

And convert your average seconds amount back to `timedelta`:

```
average = timedelta(seconds=average)
```